# Can “asher yotzar” be called part of Birkas HaTorah?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, torah-study, asher-yatzar

My chavrusa suggested that the blessings of “al netilas yodoyim” and “asher yotzar” are part of Birkas HaTorah. Is there any evidence for this please? The implication would be that even if a person had no need of the facilities, he would still need to say  “al netilas yodoyim” and “asher yotzar” as  part of Birkas HaTorah.

Comment: Do you mean "Birchas HaShachar"?

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%93_%D7%90

Comment: @DavidKenner You ask a reasonable question - but no I meant  Birkas HaTorah.

Comment: I don't see at all how those blessings could in any way be "part" of birkas hatorah (they don't mention Torah and are each recited in other contexts that have no relation to Torah), but they could still be required before learning Torah. Did your chavrusa mean the former, or the latter?

Answer (score 3):

The dinim of washing hands and asher yotzar are in Shulchan Oruch Orach Chayyim [Simon 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.4?lang=bi) and the dinim of Birkas HaTorah are in [Simon 47](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.47?lang=bi). So it seems clear that they are two separate topics.

On the point about even if a person had no need of the toilet, he would still need to say “al netilas yodoyim” and “asher yotzar”; Simon 4 says:

> ירחץ ידיו ויברך על נטילת ידים: הגה וי"א גם אשר יצר ואפי' לא עשה צרכיו
> (וכן נהגו) (אבודרהם)
>
> When one washes his hands, he should recite the blessing "...
> regarding washing the hands. Gloss: And some also say "He Who Formed"
> (Asher Yatzar), even if he did not relieve himself, and this is our
> practice (Abudirham).

The reason is not connected to Birkas HaTorah but as the Mishna Berura says:

> הטעם משום דבבוקר נעשה כבריה חדשה The reason is because he is (in the
> morning) like a new creature.